# Memory Corrupt After Fork

Tags: c++, c, memory, struct, fork

I'm getting a crash I can't yet figure out - a struct is allocated before a fork. In the struct, conditionally allocated memory is also allocated to a string. If this struct is accessed by the parent before or after the fork no problems are experienced.

When the child attempts to access the struct, all of the values in the struct's memory are garbage, but valgrind doesn't complain about memory accesses to the struct, so it appears to think the memory should be valid. However, when the string within the struct is accessed - the pointer is a garbage value - the program crashes. Valgrind points out that the memory hasn't been recently allocated or freed, but this is expected since it is a garbage value.

Has anyone experienced something similar? I haven't found any helpful hints from my searches so far.

**EDIT: conditionally allocated memory**

Comment: Can you create a simple compilable example that displays the problem? That will either a) solve it for you or b) allow us to solve it.

Comment: Is this a multithreaded application? Beware of `pthread_atfork` and such ilk.

Comment: @KerrekSB This is not a multithreaded application.

Comment: @CharlieBurns I don't believe I can do that but I'll update the question if I figure out how.

Comment: What is "conditional memory"?

Comment: Conditionally allocated memory.

Comment: Are you sure that by any chance you are not calling `vfork()` instead of `fork()`? There perhaps is some nasty `#define fork vfork` somewhere in the code.

Comment: @alk the word vfork doesn't appear anywhere in the code base. Good idea though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A fork just makes a duplicate of the memory. Therefore it was corrupt just before the fork.

Why not put a break point there or do the same memory access just before the fork to experience the same problem.

Comment: I have done exactly that and the memory isn't corrupt before or after the fork.

Comment: @dbeer - I can assure you that it is nowt to do with the fork. You need to look elsewhere

Comment: I removed the fork and it still happens - it appears to be a problem with the struct being viewed as a different size by the compiler in that module. Don't know why yet but thanks.

Comment: In case anyone is curious, the struct was a different size due to changing the order of include files.